# Calculating fundamental group of mapping torus

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

We have a simply connected space $X$ and the mapping torus $M_f \cong (X \times [0,1])/p $ where $p$ identifies $(x,0)$ with $(f(x), 1)$. For example: how do we compute the fundamental group of $X \times [0, \frac{1}{2}]$ under the image? if $f(X)$ is again simply connected then the fundamental is clearly trivial, but this may not be the case.

Now since $M_f$ is path connected, we consider w.l.o.g the basepoint $x_0 = p(x,1/2) \in M_f$ where $x \in X$.

My plan was to consider $X_1, X_2$ the images of $X \times [0, \frac{1}{2} + \epsilon], X \times [\frac{1}{2}, 1] \cup C$ under $M_f$ respectively, where $C$ denotes a circle basically connecting $p(x,0)$ and $p(x, 1/2)$, hence $X_0 = X_1 \cap X_2$ is again connected and $x_0 \in X_0$.

So we use Seifert-van-Kampen and get the following diagram:

$$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD} \pi_1(X_0, x_0) @>{}>> \pi_1(X_1, x_0)\\ @V{}VV @VV{}V\\ \pi_1(X_2, x_0) @>>{}> \pi_1(X, x0)\end{CD}$$

Now we only have to calculate the respective fundamental groups, but I don't know how to proceed. Any feedback would be appreciated, I've tried looking for similar questions on the website: [Details for calculating the fundamental group of mapping torus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2519439/details-for-calculating-the-fundamental-group-of-mapping-torus)
and [Fundamental group of mapping torus?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39589/fundamental-group-of-mapping-torus).
But they seem to be either skipping this detail or using some complicated tools that are not readily available for me yet.

Comment: Which of the terms and maps in that square have you been able to calculate?

Comment: @ronno sadly I have problem with calculating the fundamental groups since they contain either $X \times {0}$ or $X \times {1}$ under the image of $M_f$. As for the maps, they are all inclusions so just identities.

Comment: @ronno how to see that $X_1 \simeq X$ and $X_2 \simeq f(X) \vee S^1 $?

Comment: Do you know why the mapping *cylinder* of $X \to Y$ is homotopy equivalent to $Y$? Use this to show that $X_2 \simeq X \vee S^1$ and $X_0 \simeq X \vee X \vee S^1$. $X_1 \simeq X$ because it deformation retracts to $X \times 0$.

Comment: @ronno but at the same time we have $X \times 0 = f(X) \times 1$ under the image of $M_f$ does this not affect the fundamental group?

Comment: There is something to show here but essentially, because there are no identifications on $X \times [0,1)$, it turns out that $X \times [0, 1)$ maps homeomorphically onto its image in $M_f$.

Comment: @ronno yes that part is clear, but what happens with $X \times {0}$? there's an identification there.

Comment: @ronno apologies, I meant, there's an identification between $(x, 0)$ and $(f(x), 1)$