# Fundamental group of a mapping torus over a simply connected space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Let $f\colon X\to X$ be a map and $X$ simply connected. Let $M_f=X\times [0,1]/(x,0)\sim (f(x),1)$ be the mapping torus of $X$ from $f$.

I want to calculate the fundamental group $\pi_1(M_f)$. Note that this is not a homework.

---

My intuition tells me that the fundamental group is trivial since $X$ is simply connected. This is my approach:

I want to apply van Kampen, so I define $U= \text{image of } [0, \frac 1 2+\epsilon)$ and $V= \text{image of } (\frac 1 2 , 1]$. We set $W = U \cap V = (\frac 1 2 , \frac 1 2 +\epsilon)$. We have that $U,V$ and $W$ are path connected and $\mathring U \cup \mathring V = M$, so we are allowed to apply van Kampen.

Now comes the part where I'm not sure.

I think we have $\pi_1(U) = 1$ and $\pi_1(V)=1$ simply because $\pi_1(X)=1$. Therefore, by van Kampen, we get $\pi_1(M_f)=1$.

---

Is this correct? I have a gut feeling that something is wrong. This seems clueless and too simple.

If not, how to apply van Kampen then?

Comment: Small nit-pick, you want $\frac 12+\epsilon$, not $\frac1{2+\epsilon}$.

Comment: A loop around a circular portion will not be contractible just like $S^1$ is not contractible so it can't be trivial.

Comment: @CyclotomicField I see, but how to apply van Kampen then?

Comment: Your title is very dangerous. The fundamental group of the torus is certainly not trivial.

Comment: To emphasize the point raised @CyclotomicField, the one element set $X$ gives a counterexample, because the mapping cylinder of $f : X \to X$ is homeomorphic to $S^1$.

Comment: A torus can be created by extruding a circle along another circle. Use that geometric intuition to shape your proof.

Comment: Why do you want to use Van Kampen for this calculation? It's much easier to prove that $\pi_1(X \times Y, (x_0, y_0)) \simeq \pi_1(X, x_0) \times \pi_1(Y, y_0)$ straight from the definition of fundamental groups, and then appeal to the fact that the torus is $S^1 \times S^1$.

Comment: Ah- went off cocksure from the old title. Thank you.

Comment: Your $W$ is rather the image of $X\times(\{0\}\cup(\frac 1 2 , \frac 1 2 +\epsilon))$ and is therefore not path-connected. Better look at the proposed duplicate, [Details for calculating the fundamental group of mapping torus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2519439), and the posts linked to it.

Comment: @DuncanRamage I think you can delete your 2 comments

Comment: So the linked question does have an answer but it uses a lot of theory and definition not covered in our lectures yet. But since my question is a special case of that linked question, perhaps I do not actually need that theory. I have posted a follow up question with what is unclear: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4714317/details-for-calculating-the-fundamental-group-of-mapping-torus-in-detail